# Imposing page numbering when using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: vb.net, interop, ms-word, page-numbering

I have the following VB.Net code to create a Microsoft Word document. How can I impose page numbering?

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Dim wordApp As Word._Application = New  _
Word.ApplicationClass()

Dim wordDoc As Word._Document = _
    wordApp.Documents.Add()

Dim para As Word.Paragraph = wordDoc.Paragraphs.Add()
para.Range.Text = "First Page Content."
para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

para.Range.InsertBreak()

para.Range.Text = "Second Page Content."
para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
 'wdAlignPageNumberCenter=1
 wordDoc.Sections(1).Footers(1).PageNumbers.Add (1)
```